Langchain returning answers out of context
I am trying to build a tool where the users can upload a file to my hosted vectorDb in Qdrant and then they can ask question only about that file.
My tech stack includes python, streamlit, langchain, vectordb and openai api.
Right now is working well but if for example I have uploaded and stored a file in database that is about football and then question my app about History or Chemistry, it will return answers for that as well.
I want to change it and make it search the database for a relevant context, and if nothing is found, I want it to return "I don't know. Your question is not relevant to the file you have uploaded.
This is my code:
Uploading the file:
def show_page1():
st.title("Upload Your .txt Files")

uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Choose a .txt file", type="txt")
if uploaded_file is not None:
    
    text_data = process_file(uploaded_file)


    text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(
        separator="\n", 
        chunk_size=1000, 
        chunk_overlap=200, 
        length_function=len
    )
    chunks = text_splitter.split_text(text_data)


    vector_store = get_vector_store()


    document_id = uploaded_file.name


    vector_store.add_texts(chunks, metadatas=[{"document_id": document_id}] * len(chunks))

    st.success("File uploaded and stored successfully!")

    if st.button("Go to Page 2"):
        st.session_state.page = "Page 2"

Asking questions and processing them:
def show_page2():
st.title("Ask Questions About Your Documents")

vector_store = get_vector_store()

# Set up the retrieval-based QA chain
qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=OpenAI(),
    chain_type="stuff",
    retriever=vector_store.as_retriever()
)

user_question = st.text_input("Ask a question about your data:")
if user_question:
    st.write(f"Question: {user_question}")
    
    # Run the question through the retrieval QA chain
    answer = qa.run(user_question)

    if "No relevant context found" in answer:
        st.write("Your question seems to be out of context for the uploaded documents.")
    else:
        st.write(f"Answer: {answer}")

What am I missing here and why it is failing to keep track only about the data that are uploaded into vectordb and not act exactly like openAi an returning answers for anything ?

You need to include a prompt that very explicitly tells the LLM to only use the available context, and to avoid including any additional context or knowledge that it may have in answers. You'll need to "trial and error" with prompts to make this work. The joy of prompt engineering.
Right now you're simply sending the question, alongside the "most relevant" chunks of content identified from your vector store, to the LLM. The LLM doesn't know that you want it to only look at the provided content; it's just like ChatGPT, and will always try to be helpful and answer any given question.
See LangChain docs on Prompts.
